# Printing - inserting sheets between pages

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to build a macro that can print certain pages built on an input form. The issue I'm having trouble with is actually setting the custom print area to what I want. An example is below:

I want to be able to print Page 1 & 2 from "Sheet1", then insert Page 1 from "Sheet2", and then print the remaining Pages 3 & 4 from "Sheet1".

Is this possible? Ideally, I would like for Excel to then progress to print preview with all of this in the order stated above.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to preview in this order. But with VBA it should be possible to print that order. Something like the following should give you an idea.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Copies:=1
Worksheets("Sheet2").PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1
Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut From:=3, To:=4, Copies:=1
```